# Bash find and remove files in directory, but do not remove directory

Tags: bash, find, exec

For example I have a directory with backups, I want to remove files in the directory older than 6 days, but leave the directory in tact.

I currently have;

```
find /backups/daily/{databases,logs} -mtime +6 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This however, removes the directory AS WELL as the file inside. How do I leave the directories in tact but remove the files inside that are older than 6 days?

Comment: Remove the `-r` from your `rm` command

Comment: Try using `-type f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find Test -type f -mtime -1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The `type -f` did the trick, thanks